# jQuery: datepicker not functional

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to have a jQuery UI `datepicker` appear when I click on a textbox.  I am not getting any datepicker with the code below.

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themename/jquery-ui.custom.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#date").click(function(){             
    $(this).datepicker();
  });
});
</script>

<body>
<form>
 date: <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: why using click handler here? Any error in console?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ click "view source"

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date").datepicker();
});
```

it shall show the date picker when you click the text box, no need to bind it on click function.